# Wait for data from external API before making POST request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, asynchronous, ibm-watson

I'm using the IBM Watson Tone Analyser API with Express.js and React. I have this code which sends some test to the Watson API:

```
    // tone-analyser.js
    class ToneAnalysis {
      constructor() {
        const params = {
          username: process.env.USERNAME,
          password: process.env.PASSWORD,
          version_date: '2018-01-31'
        }
       this.Analyzer = new ToneAnalyzerV3(params);
      }
      ToneAnalyser(input) {
        let tones = this.Analyzer.tone(input, (err, tone) => {
          if (err) console.log(err.message)
          let voiceTone = tone.document_tone.tones[0].tone_id;
          console.log(voiceTone) // Logs the right value on Node.js console
          return voiceTone;
        });
        return tones;
     }
    }
    module.exports = ToneAnalysis;
```

I then use this on my Express backend like so:

```
    // server.js
    const ToneAnalysis = require('./api/tone-analyser');
    const app = express();
    const input = {
        tone_input: 'I am happy',
        content_type: 'text/plain'
    }
    app.get('/api/tone', (req, res) => {
        let tone = new ToneAnalysis().ToneAnalyser(input);
        return res.send({
            tone: tone
        });
    });
```

And I make an API call from React here:

```
    // App.js
    componentDidMount() {
        this.callApi()
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res.tone); // Logs the wrong value on Chrome console
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      }

      callApi = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/api/tone');
        const body = await response.json();

        if (response.status !== 200) throw new Error(body.message);
        console.log(body);
        return body;
      };
```

I expect the value of `res.tone` to be a `string` showing the tone gotten from the tone analysis function (`new ToneAnalysis().ToneAnalyser(input);`). Instead, I get

```
    {
      uri: {...},method: "POST", headers: {...}}
       headers: {...},
       uri: {...},
       __proto__: Object
    }
```

I think this happens because the `res.send(...)` runs before `tone` has a value from the API. My question is, how do I make `res.send(...)` run only after `tone` has a value?

I tried wrapping the callback function in `this.Analyzer.tone(input, [callback])` in an `async/await` block, but that did not fix the issue. Any ideas on how to fix this will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Conversation has web functions. So you can call tone analyser from within conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the call to

```
let tone = new ToneAnalysis().ToneAnalyser(input);
```

returns a promise then you could do something like

```
tone.then(res.send.bind(res))
```

Comment: It returns an object. But I figured it out thanks to your answer. I modified the `ToneAnalyser` method to return a promise instead of an object. Then I resolved it in `server.js` I grabbed the returned value using `tone.then(...)`

Comment: glad my answer helped

Answer (score 0):

If the call to

```
let tone = new ToneAnalysis()`enter code here`.ToneAnalyser(input);
```

returns a promise then you could do something like

```
tone.then(res.send.bind(res))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would edit the express route to have an async callback:

```
app.get('/api/tone', async (req, res) => {
    const analyzer = new ToneAnalysis();
    const analysis = await analyzer.ToneAnalyser(input);
    return res.send({
        tone: analysis
    });
});
```